# Movies, movies, movies!

Tags: crosswords, movies, cryptic-crosswords

Each answer is the title of a well-known movie...

[image: Movies crossword grid]

ACROSS 
4. Teardrop flows for a broken relationship (8) 
6. Spin the hated frog, until brown (3,9) 
9. Immediate disaster as Neb crewman’s sly weapon explodes (first part, before 8 down) (10) 
10. Unbalanced, like a legendary bird (5) 
13. Happy interlingual anonymous fighter (9) 
15. Disaster movie provokes small laughs (5) 
16. Prideful monarch is audibly recumbent (3,4,4) 
17. Selfish idea (now an internet phenomenon) and digit as a keepsake (7) 
19. Patents, copyrights and trademarks lost in shipwreck! (5) 
20. Taken, awaits rye dip mixture (second part, after 3 down) (4) 
22. Mechanised fruit is on time (second part, after 12 down) (6) 
23. Subway city-state, or milepost repositioned (10) 
 
DOWN 
1. A frog is confused by long-distance travel (5) 
2. Flight to the Bahamas (2) 
3. Taken, awaits rye dip mixture (first part, before 20 across) (8) 
5. Nitrate mother turns from the light to the dark side (3,10) 
7. Rick’s White House (10) 
8. Immediate disaster as Neb crewman’s sly weapon explodes (second part, after 9 across) (3) 
11. Marilyn’s Sugar is naturalised newspaper mogul (7,4) 
12. Mechanised fruit is on time (first part, before 22 across) (1,9) 
14. Shake saline strangely (6) 
18. Threat mix disrupted Blair’s chambers (3,6) 
21. Moot-like heist turns farcical (first part, before 25 down) (4,4) 
24. Nutty carbohydrate, gangnam-style (6) 
25. Moot-like heist turns farcical (second part, after 21 down) (2,3)

Comment: Ah, excellent! Another one.

Comment: Seemingly quite a bit easier than the last one, to judge by the speed of solution. Very nice puzzle though! Why did you accept the answer with no explanations? That can be an [issue](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/2825/5373) sometimes.

Comment: OK, it does have (short) explanations now. No links though :-p

Comment: @randal'thor, yeah, I was really surprised how quickly this one was solved, given the previous one took weeks! I guess maybe restricting the topic to films helps a lot, or maybe I've just got over the "clues too difficult" phase of my puzzle-setting. Possibly I did too many anagrams this time, too easy. Re the accepted answer, it just had the most clues solved first, I figured explanations could come later.

Comment: It got on the HNQs as well - nice job! Re speed of solution, I guess most people know more about films than novels. Even I (a complete film numbskull) managed quite a few clues; I would've done much more on the previous one had I not been suspended when you posted it!

Comment: Maybe too many anagrams? I love anagrams and think they're an essential part of good crosswords, but they can also be pretty easy to solve, especially on the internet with access to tools like [this](http://wordsmith.org/anagram). PS: #3 on HNQs.

Comment: Maybe you should create a CW answer with *all* the solutions and explanations? I still don't understand "Apocalypse Now".

Comment: @randal'thor, yeah, maybe too many anagrams. True, that one hasn't been fully explained..... I'll leave you to figure it out. :) What kind of movie-related vessel might "Neb" be?

Comment: The only thing it made me think of was [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castaways_of_the_Flying_Dutchman).

Comment: @randal'thor right name, wrong vessel. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. > Fargo (Anagram of "A Frog")
2. > Up (Two-letter word, "Flight")
3. > Spirited Away (Anagram of "Awaits rye dip")
4. > Predator (Anagram of "Teardrop")
5. > The Terminator (Anagram of "Nitrate mother")
6. > The Godfather (Anagram of "The hated frog")
7. > Casablanca (Means "white house")
8. (See 9)
9. > Apocalypse Now ("Disaster", "Immediate")
10. > Rocky ("Unbalanced", Roc-like)
11. > Citizen Kane ("Newspaper mogul")
12. > A Clockwork Orange
13. ???
14. > Aliens (Anagram of "Saline")
15. > Gigli
16. > The Lion King ("Pride" -> Lion, "Monarch" -> King)
17. > Memento ("Keepsake")
18. ???
19. > Shrek (Subsequence of "shipwreck")
20. (See 3)
21. ???
22. (See 12)
23. > Metropolis (Anagram of "Or milepost")
24. > Psycho (Psy + CHO)
25. ??? (See 21)

Thanks to [rand al'thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373/rand-althor) for (7) and [Christian Rau](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/10215/christian-rau) for (15)

Comment: Nearly solved - that was quick! :)

Comment: Explanations please?

Comment: Done already. Please check :)

Answer (score 5):

**12 down and 22 across**

> Mechanised fruit is on time (1,9;6)

Solution:

> [A Clockwork Orange](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0066921/). An easy one to get me started!

**1 down**

> A frog is confused by long-distance travel (5)

Solution:

> [Fargo](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116282/) - an anagram of "a frog" and related to long-distance travel. (Thanks to **crazyiman** for helping me with this one.)

**7 down**

> Rick’s White House (10)

Solution:

> [Casablanca](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0034583/). The main character is named Rick, and Casablanca literally means "white house". (I got this by assuming Casablanca must be somewhere in the puzzle and just finding a 10-letter clue!)

**17 across**

> Selfish idea (now an internet phenomenon) and digit as a keepsake (7)

Solution:

> [Memento](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0209144/). An internet phenomenon is a meme (hello AE, your favourite!), originating from an idea of selfishness in genetics. A to(e) is a digit, and the whole thing is a keepsake.

**2 down**

> Flight to the Bahamas (2)

Solution:

> [Up](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1049413/). The airline code for Bahamas Air is UP.

**14 down**

> Shake saline strangely (6)

Solution:

> [Aliens](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090605/). It's an anagram of saline, and aliens are strange!

**24 down**

> Nutty carbohydrate, gangnam-style (6)

Partial solution:

> Gangnam Style is a pop single by the South Korean musician Psy, so I'd guess this ends with the letters PSY.

**6 across**

> Spin the hated frog, until brown (3,9)

Solution:

> [The Godfather](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646/?ref_=chttp_tt_2). This is an anagram of "the hated frog", and [James Brown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Brown) is known as the "godfather of soul". Again I got this just by guessing this film must be in here and searching for a (3,9) clue.

**18 down**

> Threat mix disrupted Blair’s chambers (3,6)

Solution:

> [The Matrix](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0133093/?ref_=chttp_tt_18). This is an anagram of "threat mix", and Cherie Blair used to be in Matrix Chambers (thanks again to **crazyiman** for helping with this clue). Again I got this just by looking for a (3,6) clue.

Comment: Go far -> Fargo

Comment: Oh and on the Rick clue, check the title of the play on which the movie was based.

Comment: Re 6 across, who by the name of 'brown' might match the solution? ;)

Comment: Matrix, Blair and Chambers might be related to this : http://www.independent.co.uk/news/people/cherie-booth-quits-chambers-to-join-international-consultancy-with-clients-including-kazakhstans-government-9758363.html

Comment: @crazyiman, yes indeed. :)

Comment: @AE http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Brown ?

Comment: @randal'thor, exactly. :)

Answer (score 3):

15 across

> [Gigli](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0299930/) - A "giggle" is a small laugh and that movie *was* an utter disaster.

11 down

> [Citizen Kane](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0033467/) - Made the connection from "sugar cane" and the fact that he's a newspaper mogul (and of course, that movie has to be in there anyway). Don't know how Marilyn figures into this, though.

16 across, a bit obscure, but fitting to the other letters

> [The Lion King](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110357/) - A lion king is obviously a "prideful monarch" and he's "audibly recumbent" because *"lion"* sounds like *"lying"*.

23 across

> [Metropolis](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0017136/) - A "metro" is a subway, a "polis" a greek city state.

24 down

> [Psycho](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0054215/) - PSY is the Korean rapper who sang "Gangnam Style" (as *rand al'thor* already deduced) and a carbohydrate contains carbon (C), hydrogen (H) and oxygen (O).

5 down

> [The Terminator](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088247/) - Anagram of "nitrate mother", not sure about light and dark side, though. Also the word for the separation line between light and dark on illuminated planets.

10 across

> [Rocky](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075148/) - A "rocky" surface is uneven/unbalanced. Not sure about the bird, though, maybe a reference to *Chicken Run*.

Comment: Both right, nice work Christian. For the Marilyn thing, google her with the connection you've already made. ;)

Comment: For 5 down, the answer has an alternative meaning to do with light and dark...

Comment: @AE Ah, you mean the astronomic one.

Comment: Christian, that's it. Clear as day and night. :)

Answer (score 3):

Great quiz. :) The missing pieces:

**13**

> Gladiator. Happy=Glad, not sure about the rest

**21** and **25**

> Some Like It Hot, from the letters of 'Moot-like heist'

Comment: Glad you liked it! :)